# Swiping multiple questions on Android app feed interferes with the side drawers

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

When I try to swipe multiple questions in the feed - from left to right, I almost always open the left-side navigation drawer instead.

That's not handy.

Comment: I corrected some terms based on latest version's interface (v1.0.83). If you feel that the edit invalidates your issue, feel free to rollback. However, if that's the case, then it might be closed as no-repro since there are many updates until current version that might change/fix it. (Personally, I don't face the issue on current version: you can swipe it on the center without interfering both side drawers)